# Concatenating lines with sed based on the length of a line

Tags: awk, sed, concatenation

Essentially, I want to read a file and concatenate each line to the next line, only if the first line has a length of less than 6. (Six is the maximum length of a chapter "number".)

```
16.
Chapter Name
17.
Chapter Name 
Appendix
A.1.
Appendix name
A.2.
Appendix name
```

In this example the output would be:

```
16. Chapter name
17. Chapter Name 
Appendix
A.1. Appendix name
A.2. Appendix name
```

Using this:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

results in:

```
16. Chapter Name
17. Chapter Name 
Appendix A.1.
Appendix name A.2.
Appendix name
```

Does sed support the use of logic to move a line to the hold buffer based on its length (or if it fits a pattern)?

Would awk be a better option?

Comment: sed is not the right tool for that task, use awk instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s", $0 (length($0)<6?" ":ORS)}' foo
16. Chapter Name
17. Chapter Name
Appendix
A.1. Appendix name
A.2. Appendix name
```

Comment: Awesome! This works perfectly, Many thanks Mr. Brown.

Comment: Just wish you'd used OFS instead of hard-coding " ": `printf "%s%s", $0, (length($0)<6?OFS:ORS)`. I prefer specifying 2 separate strings as the data args to printf rather than doing concatenation into one but that's arguably just a style choice and it'd only matter if you had some ambiguous unparenthesized expression (e.g. try `echo 'h' | awk '{printf "%s\n", $0 ++cnt}'` vs `echo 'h' | awk '{printf "%s%s\n", $0, ++cnt}'`).

Comment: @EdMorton `OFS` got left out by choice because the code concatenated chapter names to chapter numbers and I couldn't see any other separator between them. Regarding `%s%s` vs `%s` that's a nice example, never really gave it a thought (but had to try the first one with `""`).

Answer (score 1):

With sed:

```
$ sed -r 'N;/^(.){,5}\n/s/\n/ /;P;D' infile 
16. Chapter Name
17. Chapter Name 
Appendix
A.1. Appendix name
A.2. Appendix name
```

- Extended regexes (`-r`) are just used so I didn't have to type `\(.\)\{,5\}`.
- `N;P;D` creates a moving two-line window: `N` appends the next line to the pattern space, `P` prints the first line of the pattern space, and `D` deletes it.
- `/^(.){,5}\n/` matches if the pattern space contains five or fewer characters before the newline
- If this matches, `s/\n/ /` concatenates the two lines

The hold space isn't required for this, but if it were, you could copy the pattern space based on its length with the same regex as used here.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` solution

```
$ sed -E '/^.{,5}$/{N; s/\n/ /}' ip.txt 
16. Chapter Name
17. Chapter Name 
Appendix
A.1. Appendix name
A.2. Appendix name
```

- `/^.{,5}$/` if line has maximum of 5 characters

  - `N;` get next line
  - `s/\n/ /` substitute the first `\n` with space
- Some `sed` versions use `-r` instead of `-E` for extended regex

And another `perl` solution

```
$ perl -lpe '$_ .= " ".<> if length() < 6; chomp' ip.txt 
16. Chapter Name
17. Chapter Name 
Appendix
A.1. Appendix name
A.2. Appendix name
```

- `$_` contains the current line
- `$_ .= " ".<> if length() < 6` append space and next line if current line is less than 6 characters
- `chomp` remove ending new line character if present from `$_`. Required because the next line obtained by `<>` would have `\n` character
- `-l` option removes ending `\n` from input lines and adds it back while printing
- `-p` iterate over input files in a loop, `$_` value is printed by default at end of all commands

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -pe 'chomp; $_.=(length()<6?" ":"\n")' file
```

`chomp` removes the newline
`$_` is the current line
The ternary `?` `:` operator either appends a space or a newline

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'sub(/\.$/,". "){printf $0;next}1' file

16. Chapter Name
17. Chapter Name 
Appendix
A.1. Appendix name
A.2. Appendix name
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.